# Python: finding the closest value in a list less than or greater than a input value, excluding the input value itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, closest

Is there a way to find the closest value from a list that is either less than or greater than a value gathered by input? The input value has to be excluded from the possible values.

I've used this, but it gives back the input value if it is in the list. I do not want to get that value back. I'm trying to find the closest value lees than or greater than the input.

```
closeVal = lambda myList : abs(myList - inputValue) 

closeVal = min(myList, key=closeVal)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the same name for the function and result. It's confusing and it prevents you from using the function multiple times. Also, use `def` to define named functions, not `lambda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out the input values before getting the minimum.

```
closeVal = min([x for x in myList if x != inputValue], key=lambda y: abs(inputValue - y))
```

Comment: if x < inputValue should be x != inputValue

Comment: I misread the question, I didn't see `or greater than`